# How to allow new View.OnClickListener() to function in android studio?

Tags: android

I am a starter in Android Studio and I am working on the program that reads user input and process the information. I ran into this problem that user input is not getting processed at all even though I did follow the tutorials and videos. Here's the code in MainActivity.java.

```
package com.example.postcodechecker;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    int postalcodeinputvalue;

    EditText postalcodeinput;

    Button submit;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        postalcodeinput = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.postalcodeinput);

        Button submit = findViewById(R.id.submit);
        submit.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view){
                postalcodeinputvalue = Integer.valueOf(postalcodeinput.getText().toString());

                showToast(String.valueOf(postalcodeinputvalue));

            }

        });

    }


    private void showToast(String text) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, text, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

note that new View.OnClickListener() isn't doing anything as the font colour is gray in the editor.

This is the layout file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:scaleX="1"
    android:scaleY="1"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="50dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="50dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="120dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="50dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="50dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
            android:fontFamily="sans-serif-condensed"
            android:text="Welcome to the Postal Code checker"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body1"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"></TextView>

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/postalcodeinput"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="Enter your postal code here"
            android:inputType="number" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/submit"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="check" />

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
'''

Thanks a lot if you would like to give some help.
```

Answer (score 0):

You are passing an Integer to the function ShowText but the constructor expects a String. Do this.

Change

```
showToast(String.valueOf(postalcodeinputvalue));
```

To

```
showToast(postalcodeinput.getText().toString());
```

Comment: Yours worked as well! It turns out to just be my AVD's problem - I changed one and it worked. Thanks a lot anyways.